# How do you resize a top level UIView in Xcode 4.5.2 Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a UIScrollView with about three screen length's worth of stuff inside. Trying to design for it in the Interface Builder is proving difficult because I cannot resize the top level UIView to be longer than the screen size (or resize it at all).

Please note I have set all simulated metrics in the View Controller to None AND set the Size to Freeform. Auto layout is also disabled. This has NOT let me resize it - all my research on this issue has only yielded these solutions and it seems to work for everyone but me, has something changed in Xcode 4.5.2 or am I missing something?

Comment: Move the scroll view up into the negative Y range, do what you need to do, and move it back?

Comment: This should work. Have you tried restarting Xcode?  4.5.2 is rather old too, maybe you should upgrade to the latest version, 4.6.2 by now.

Comment: I updated to 4.6.2 and thus restarted it as well in the process. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Thanks Kirill Shlenskiy for your workaround suggestion, it may be a bit less convenient than resizing but it's better than nothing. I will do this until I can figure out why the resizing isn't working for me.